# Create a view that contain the employee prior experience year fields as the column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

my table-1 is like:

```
id    name
1     ann
2     Kim
3     joe
4     Reb
5     anu
```

table-2 is like:

```
id  start_date  employer
1   8/7/2011    Wipro
1   9/6/2012    Sutherland
2   1/7/2010    Infosys
2   7/9/2011    Wipro
3   8/2/2011    Infosys
3   9/8/2012    cape_gemini
3   8/6/2013    Wipro
```

I want to create a 'view' fro these two tables
the output is like:

```
id   name    2010       2011          2012         2013
1    and     null      Wipro         Sutherland     null
2    Kim    Infosys    Wipro         null           null
3    joe    null       Infosys       cape_gemini   Wipro
```

Comment: And what hav you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: how to create columns which have the year and how to enter the employer there? @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pivot. like this

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT
  T1.ID,
  T1.NAME,
  T2.Employer,
  start_date = YEAR(T2.start_date)
  FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2
      ON T1.ID = T2.ID
 )
 select
 *
 from cte
 pivot
 (
     max(employer)
   for
   start_date in
   (
     [2010],[2011],[2012],[2013]
     )
)pvt
```

Result

[image]

Comment: is this query create a view? @Jayasurya Satheesh

Comment: just add a create view statement on the first line to make it a view

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by executing a dynamic SQL query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select t1.id, t1.name, ' + stuff((
        select distinct ', max(case datepart(year, t2.[start_date]) when ' 
        + cast(datepart(year, [start_date]) as varchar(4))
        + ' then [employer] end) as [' 
        + cast(datepart(year, [start_date]) as varchar(4)) + ']'
        from [table2]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 2, ''
);

select @sql += ' from [table1] t1 
                 join [table2] t2 
                 on t1.[id] = t2.[id] 
                 group by t1.[id], t1.[name];';

exec(@sql);
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/AMWSB98091)**

Comment: how this query apply for creating a view? I want a 'view ' query @Wanderer

Comment: please help me to create a 'view' using this query @Wanderer

Comment: @AnuAntony : Just add `create view [your_view_name] as` at the beginning of `@sql` variable.

Answer (score 0):

see this modified query
Note: View should be created in separate window.

```
create  table tab(id int,name varchar(20))
insert into tab
select 1,'ann'
union all
select 2,'Kim'
union all
select 3,'joe'
union all
select 4,'Reb'
union all
select 5,'anu'
select * from tab

create  table tab1 (id int, start_date datetime, employer varchar(30))
insert into tab1
select 1  ,'8/7/2011','Wipro'
union all
select 1  ,'9/6/2012' ,   'Sutherland'
union all
select 2  ,'1/7/2010'  ,  'Infosys'
union all
select 2  ,'7/9/2011'   , 'Wipro'
union all
select 3  ,'8/2/2011'    ,'Infosys'
union all
select 3  ,'9/8/2012'    ,'cape_gemini'
union all
select 3  ,'8/6/2013'    ,'Wipro'
select * from tab1

create view v_emp_Details
 as
with emp_details (id ,e_name ,join_dte ,company )
as
(select t2.id,t1.name,t2.start_date,t2.employer
from tab t1
inner join tab1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id)

select * from 
(select id,e_name,datepart(yy,join_dte) as d,company from emp_details ) t
pivot (max(t.company) for t.d in ([2010],[2011],[2012],[2013])) as q


select * from v_emp_Details
```

view output

```
id  e_name  2010    2011    2012        2013
1   ann     NULL    Wipro   Sutherland  NULL
2   Kim     Infosys Wipro   NULL        NULL
3   joe     NULL    Infosys cape_gemini Wipro
```

Comment: please help me to create a 'view' using this query